# Getting file size of data when using requests.get and shutil copy object

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests, get, shutil

with requests.get(….) as r:
With open(filepath,’wb’)
r.raw.decode_content = True
shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw,f)

Initially we used to take file size as len(chunk)

Comment: What is chunk in your "code"? and what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: For chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1028).   So here it was east to take length of chunk and add it to get final size

Comment: len(r.content) will give you the size of the response in bytes

Answer (score 0):

To get the total file length you need to sum each chunk together.

Example:

```
import requests

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:

    with open(some_path, 'wb') as f:
        file_size = 0
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1028):
            file_size += len(chunk)
            f.write(chunk)
```

The final `file_size` will be the size in bytes to change the unit will need to do additional calculations

```
import math

print(math.ceil(file_size / 1024), 'KB')
```

Prints the file size in KB.
I tested this with a random image and the stdout matches the file size that windows explorer says for me so I believe this correct.